# Will NMEA support the GNxx string in future?

Tags: nmea

At the moment there is no problem when using GPS only devices, NMEA string with information about speed, DOP value etc starts with GP.. prefix. But with Glonass included NMEA string has different prefix GN.. and information about DOP and speed are not recognized in Qgis. Is it planned to update this also?
Position is ok, in both cases.
regards,
radek

Comment: Best to open a feature request on hub.qgis.org .

Answer (score 1):

Yes
NMEA supports GNSS string.
It gives Data in different strings like GNGGA , GPGST, etc. According to our requirements we have to mkae NMEA parser to get Data from those Strings.( I tested it in Geode device manufacture by Juniper system)